# How to convert 02 to FEB

Tags: php

How to convert 02 to FEB, where is this process come from native function of php. like `date('Y')` then we will get this year.

example like this

```
<?php
$var = 02;
$var = convertToMonthName($var);
// Output var will be 'FEB'
?>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$m = strftime("%b",mktime(0,0,0,$month));`

Answer (score 2):

```
<? php
$var = 02;
$var = convertToMonthName($var);

function convertToMonthName($n)
      {
      $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $n, 1, 2011);
      return date("M", $timestamp);
      }
?>
```

Its a bit of a hack, but it works. It creates a time stamp for the first of that month in an arbitrary year. Then it pulls the month from it using the php date function

Comment: That's a nifty idea, just remember to have the timezone set using date_default_timezone_set somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of months like this:

```
<?php
$months = array(
    1 => 'Jan',
    2 => 'Feb'
);

echo $months[02];
```

Comment: Hmm.. im sorry, i mean maybe there is will be something code which that is native function from PHP to do that...

Comment: Not anything that I know of offhand I'm afraid.